# strtotime doesn't work correnctly. put "+1 day" on arg but nothing changed

Tags: php

I would like to get next day.

```
$nextSunday = date($saturdayList[$k], strtotime("+1 day"));
```

saturdayList array is

```
Array
(
    [
    0
] => 2022-11-05
    [
    1
] => 2022-11-12
    [
    2
] => 2022-11-19
    [
    3
] => 2022-11-26
)
```

When $k is 0
nextSunday return

2022-11-05

Comment: Shouldn't it return 2022-11-06?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the manual page for the date function here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php.

You can see that the first param should be the format of the returned date, e.g. `'Y-m-d'`, not the date you want to add 1 day to.

The code should be something like

```
$nextSunday = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($saturdayList[$k] . " +1 day"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of `strtotime` takes a base timestamp. So pass in the timestamp of the date as the second parameter.

`$nextSunday = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($saturdayList[$k])));`